# Why does cat call read() twice when once was enough?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, chardev

I am new to Linux kernel module. I am learning char driver module based on a web course. I have a very simple module that creates a `/dev/chardevexample`, and I have a question for my understanding:

When I do `echo "hello4" > /dev/chardevexample`, I see the `write` execute exactly once as expected. However, when I do `cat /dev/chardevexample`, I see the read executed *two* times.

I see this both in my code and in the course material. All the data was returned in the first `read()`, so why does `cat` call it again?

All the things I did so far are as follows:

1. `insmod chardev.ko` to load my module
2. `echo "hello4" > /dev/chardevexample`. This is the write and I see it happening exactly once in dmesg
3. `cat /dev/chardevexample`. This is the read, and `dmesg` shows it happening twice.
4. I did `strace cat /dev/chardevexample`, and I indeed see the function call being called twice for read. There is a write in between as well

   ```
   read(3, "hello4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 4096
   write(1, "hello4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"...,    4096hello4) = 4096
   read(3, "", 131072)
   ```
5. `dmesg` after read (cat command)

   ```
   [909836.517402] DEBUG-device_read: To User  hello4 and bytes_to_do 4096 ppos 0 # Read #1 
   [909836.517428] DEBUG-device_read: Data send to app hello4, nbytes=4096        # Read #1   
   [909836.519086] DEBUG-device_read: To User   and bytes_to_do 0 ppos 4096       # Read #2  
   [909836.519093] DEBUG-device_read: Data send to app hello4, nbytes=0           # Read #2
   ```
6. Code snippet for read, write and file_operations is attached. Any
   guidance would help. I searched extensively and couldn't understand.
   Hence the post.

   ```
   /*!
    * @brief Write to device from userspace to kernel space
    * @returns     Number of bytes written
    */

   static ssize_t device_write(struct file *file,  //!< File pointer
                                   const char *buf,//!< from for copy_from_user. Takes 'buf' from user space and writes to 
                                                   //!< kernel space in 'buffer'. Happens on fwrite or write 
                                   size_t lbuf,    //!< length of buffer
                                   loff_t *ppos)   //!< position to write to
   {
           int nbytes = lbuf - copy_from_user(
                                              buffer + *ppos,      /* to */
                                              buf,                 /* from */
                                              lbuf);               /* how many bytes */
           *ppos += nbytes;
           buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; // Remove End of line character
           pr_info("Recieved data \"%s\" from apps, nbytes=%d\n", buffer, nbytes);
           return nbytes;
   }

   /*!
    * @brief Read from device - from kernel space to user space
    * @returns     Number of bytes read
    */
   static ssize_t device_read(struct file *file,//!< File pointer
                              char *buf,   //!< for copy_to_user. buf is 'to' from buffer
                          size_t lbuf, //!< Length of buffer
                          loff_t *ppos)//!< Position {
       int nbytes;
       int maxbytes;
       int bytes_to_do;
       maxbytes = PAGE_SIZE -  *ppos;
       if(maxbytes >lbuf)
               bytes_to_do = lbuf;
       else
               bytes_to_do = maxbytes;

       buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; // Remove End of line character
       printk("DEBUG-device_read: To User  %s and bytes_to_do %d ppos %lld\n", buffer + *ppos, bytes_to_do, *ppos);
       nbytes = bytes_to_do - copy_to_user(
                                       buf, /* to */
                                       buffer + *ppos, /* from */
                                       bytes_to_do); /* how many bytes*/
       *ppos += nbytes;
       pr_info("DEBUG-device_read: Data send to app %s, nbytes=%d\n", buffer, nbytes);
       return nbytes;} /* Every Device is like a file - this is device file operation */ static struct file_operations device_fops = {
           .owner = THIS_MODULE,
           .write = device_write,
           .open  = device_open,
           .read  = device_read,};
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Unix convention for indicating end-of-file is to have `read` return 0 bytes.

In this case, `cat` asks for 131072 bytes and only receives 4096. This is normal and not to be interpreted as having reached the end of the file. For example, it happens when you read from the keyboard but the user only inputs a small amount of data.

Because `cat` has not yet seen EOF (i.e. `read` did not return 0), it continues to issue `read` calls until it does. This means that if there's any data, you will always see a minimum of two read calls: one (or more) for the data, and one final one that returns 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This makes sense now. Dumb question, why is cat asking for 131072 Bytes and can I change it?

Comment: GNU cat asks for 128 kiB (131072 bytes) because the maintainer empirically determined this to have the best performance with the lowest memory usage on contemporary hardware (20 years ago it was 4096). To read a file with a given buffer size, you can instead use `dd bs=1234 if=myfilename`

Comment: Thanks again. for some reason dd bs=1234 was still reading more than text content. Based on other answers, dd count=8 iflag=count_bytes if=/dev/chardevexample and iI see only one read. Is this correct?

Comment: If you want to do a single read of 8 bytes, use `dd bs=8 count=1 if=/dev/chardevexample`. Obviously these are all just workarounds for the bugs in your module.

Comment: Thanks. yes this works and appears as the better usage than what I was using.

Comment: @Dsrivast The question had several issues: 1. "understanding question on read" is not a helpful title and does not help people know if this is the problem they have, 2. It did not mention what you expected or why, 3. The steps to reproduce are very hard to replicate: for example, there's only partial source code and no build command. 4. If you had tried `strace cat` on any other file you'd see it's unrelated to your module, so it could have been a simple "Why does `echo hello | strace -e read cat` shows two read calls when the first one returned all the data?"