# Questions on the linux kernel module `call twice on read proc file`; how only called tweice, how to ensure data integrity

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am writing my first kernel module, and noticed the initially strange behavior surrounding the 'one cat, two read calls'. Doing some research, it seems to be how files are read; `read()` calls until `read()` returns zero, which makes sense. [1](https://linux.kernel.narkive.com/l11NV0o3/strace-on-cat-proc-my-file-gives-results-by-calling-read-twice-why) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045498/why-does-cat-call-read-twice-when-once-was-enough)

This to me only raises more questions though:

1. Why is only one response returned from `cat`? How does `cat` receive a `0`? If my code always returns something on it's `read()` function, how can a program like `cat` ever read `0`? The second (and so on) calls would always return data, as there is nothing in the module code to return `0`.
2. how can I program a module to ensure data safety? Assume my module is a producer, and the system I am building needs data integrity to ensure each `read()` call provides the next bit of data. If a `read()` call inherently ends up needing to call at least twice to get `0` back as `EOF` (between individual records), how can I ensure integrity? This might show my lack of knowledge on available options, and not knowing what I don't know sort of thing.
3. It is known to never trust you can get an entire stream of data in one `read()` call in C, which is why we read until `EOF`. Yet the semantics of how the module's `read()` function is called suggest that something (kernel?) should be managing that data transfer, and inserting an `EOF` for the module (to be clear, my thought here is that the module writes the buffer to kernel, kernel can chunk, whatever as it passes back to user, and `EOF` is inserted by kernel). This obviously isn't the case. Any notes on this idea?

#### Code:

```c
static unsigned long numCalls = 0;

static ssize_t custom_read(struct file* file, char __user* user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t* offset){
        printk(KERN_INFO "calling our very own custom read method.");

        char* output = kasprintf(GFP_KERNEL, "Hello world! Read No: %ld\n", ++numCalls);

        if(!output){
                return -ENOMEM;
        }

        int outputLen = strlen(output);

        if (*offset > 0){
                kfree(output);
                return 0;
        }

        copy_to_user(user_buffer, output, outputLen);
        kfree(output);
        *offset = outputLen;
        return outputLen;
}
```

Which when loaded/ run:

```
$ cat /proc/helloworlddriver 
Hello world! Read No: 1
$ cat /proc/helloworlddriver 
Hello world! Read No: 3
```

Verification from `dmesg` that the function is being called twice for every `cat`:

```
$ dmesg
[ 6976.958236] calling our very own custom read method.
[ 6977.156778] calling our very own custom read method.
[ 6977.156892] calling our very own custom read method.
[ 6977.369510] calling our very own custom read method.
```

Comment: `Why is only one response` What do you mean by "response"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Added detail to show that

Comment: Och, you are asking why `cat` _when working with your module_ works? Do you understand what `if (*offset > 0){` does?

Comment: I'm asking deeper questions on how/why it works the way it does, and how to properly operate with it. My module seems to work as intended/ coded, but the behavior seems strange from a newbie like myself. I suppose I do not!

Comment: On the first call, `*offset` is zero, and gets  incremented - `*offset = outputLen;`. Then, on the second call, `*offset` is greater than zero, so your code does `return 0;`. There's nothing really much more to it..

Comment: Ah, that does make sense, I was unaware of the semantics there. That makes for some interesting implementation, and how one could split up data of a read. If you make an answer, I'll mark it green